# Is there a sudoedit equivalent for vimdiff?

Tags: vim, sudo, vimrc, sudoedit, vimdiff

I'm trying to get into the habit of editing root-owned files with `sudoedit`, instead of `sudo vim`. This has a few advantages, one of which is that it uses my user's `~/.vimrc`.

Is there an equivalent, instead of using `sudo vimdiff`?

### What I've tried

- Instead of using `vimdiff` directly, one can open two files in vertical splits, then run `:diffthis` in both. However, if I open up one file with `sudoedit`, then I'd have to open the second file directly, instead of `sudoedit` automatically creating a copy of this file in `/var/tmp`.
- One can also open files directly in splits using `vim -O file1 file2`. However, unsurprisingly, `sudoedit -O` fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To determine what editor to run, `sudo` checks three environment variables (in order): `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, and `EDITOR`, and uses the first editor it finds.  (If it doesn't find one, it falls back to a default.)

So you can make it run vimdiff instead of vim as follows:

```
$ VISUAL=vimdiff sudoedit file1 file2
```

If your sudoers policy only lets you edit certain files, this might fail, in which case you can add a parameter:

```
$ VISUAL='vimdiff file1' sudoedit file2
```

In that case, I'm assuming you can read `file1` as a normal user, but need root access to read `file2`.

(I'm using `VISUAL` because that's what I'm used to; feel free to use `SUDO_EDITOR` instead.)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that. Nice and clean. It's now an alias in `~/.bashrc`: `alias sudovimdiff='SUDO_EDITOR=vimdiff sudoedit'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddly solution. Please feel free to optimise it! Perhaps this might work in `~/vimrc`?

Open both files with `sudoedit`

```
$ sudoedit file1 file2
```

[Vertically split one buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697964/1944384)

```
:vsp | b2
```

In each window, run

```
:diffthis
```