# How can I make `sudo crontab -e` use my `sudoedit` environment?

Tags: vim, sudo, cron, vimrc, sudoedit

I've started using `sudoedit <file>` instead of `sudo vim <file>`. One of the advantages is that it uses my local `~/.vimrc`. However, when using `sudo crontab -e`, it uses `/root/.vimrc` instead. Is there a way to make `sudo crontab -e` use my local `~/.vimrc`?

Here is a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186715/is-there-a-sudoedit-equivalent-for-vimdiff), about using `sudoedit` with `vimdiff`. However, substituting `crontab -e` for `vimdiff` doesn't work.

Comment: It's related to incomplete and complete using of new user, it means you have to use complete or incomplete in all of items and a good example for using of shell environment is `su -` looking for same thing in sudo

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. There is no new user, and I'm not sure what you mean by "incomplete and complete".

Comment: Suppose all of your command OR doesn't use shell enviorment or use shell environment, When some of them use and some of thm don't use , it means incomplete and complete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you *want* to be editing `root`'s crontab, `sudo` must give you root authority.  After it does so, `crontab` will invoke `${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}` (it'll use `$VISUAL` unless it doesn't exist; in that case it'll use `$EDITOR` unless it doesn't exist; in that case it'll use `vi`).

You have a few possible solutions.  They all subvert the security provided by `sudo`, but you must already be aware of those issues (and be willing to protect your `.vimrc`) or you wouldn't be using `sudoedit` in the first place.

The best is probably to add an assignment to the `HOME` variable on the `sudo` command line so `crontab` thinks the HOME directory is different:

```
sudo HOME=$HOME crontab -e
```

(That command won't work if there's whitespace in your home directory path!)

Comment: It looks like this might be as good as it gets. However, it's missing out on some of the other advantages of `sudoedit`. For example admins can restrict users to `sudoedit`, rather than `sudo vim`. If they use the latter, they can execute arbitrary commands as root, e.g. `:! rm foo`. This suffers from similar vulnerabilities. However, in a real world environment, access to root's crontab is just as vulnerable.