# Can I sudoedit a file in a writable directory when using vimdiff?

Tags: permissions, sudo, vim, root, sudoedit

When I want to `vimdiff` root files, I use the following alias, as per [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186717/18887).

```
alias sudovimdiff='SUDO_EDITOR=vimdiff sudoedit'
```

I can then use the following command.

```
$ sudovimdiff /root/a /root/b
```

However, if one of the files is writable by my user, the command fails.

```
$ sudovimdiff /root/a /tmp/b
sudoedit: /tmp/b: editing files in a writable directory is not permitted
```

Is there a way to vimdiff one root and one non-root file, using my user's environment settings (i.e. `sudoedit`)?

Comment: I'm missing something.  Why can't you just copy the file?  Or do you mean a file that's only *readable* by `root`?

Comment: @Wildcard I quote the error above, but it causes an error with files in a *writable* directory. [Apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356145/18887) it relates to security issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be useful related to that sudoedit error message:

> sudoedit: ... editing files in a writable directory is not
>   permitted

Please try a modification to sudoers file using `sudo visudo`, add a line:

```
Defaults  !sudoedit_checkdir
```

More [here](https://www.smarinov.com/weblog/sudoedit-not-working/).

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you think of any negatives to making this option unset?

Comment: No exact stance, nor idea why things changed about 2016. I didn't see that error before that.

Answer (score 3):

From [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html), in the part describing `-e` (aka `sudoedit`):

```
 To help prevent the editing of unauthorized files, the
 following restrictions are enforced unless explicitly allowed
 by the security policy:

 ·   Symbolic links may not be edited (version 1.8.15 and
     higher).

 ·   Symbolic links along the path to be edited are not
     followed when the parent directory is writable by the
     invoking user unless that user is root (version 1.8.16
     and higher).
 ·   Files located in a directory that is writable by the
     invoking user may not be edited unless that user is root
     (version 1.8.16 and higher).
```

So, either:

- we invoke `sudoedit` as root, which would defeat the purpose or
- we copy the user's file to new directory not editable by the user:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/foo
  cp /tmp/b /tmp/foo
  chmod a-w /tmp/foo
  sudoedit /root/a /tmp/foo/b
  ```
- we edit the root file and diff it inside:

  ```
  sudoedit /root/a
  # in Vim
  :vert diffsplit /tmp/b
  ```
- since `sudoedit` treats all non-sudo arguments filenames, you could use a wrapper script:

  ```
  $ cat foo.sh
  #! /bin/sh
  exec vimdiff "$@" "$DIFF_FILE"

  $ SUDO_EDITOR ="$PWD/foo.sh" DIFF_FILE="$PWD/.zshrc" sudoedit /etc/zsh/zshrc
  [sudo] password for muru:
  2 files to edit
  sudoedit: /etc/zsh/zshrc unchanged
  ```

Comment: Thanks muru (+1). I think the last version is the least fiddly, although it'd be nice to specify both files with the initial command. I tested vim's `-c <command>`, but sudoedit won't take that. Presumably there are no other options?

Comment: @Sparhawk sudoedit treats all arguments as filenames, so the only way to pass on options to Vim via sudoedit would be to write a wrapper script. So as long as you have to specify a user-editable file, this would be a problem. See update for a possible wrapper script.

Comment: Gosh, that's pretty clunky, too. I think the third is still probably easier. Looks like it can't be done in a simple fashion, so I'll accept this answer, unless anything else comes along. Cheers.

Comment: @Sparhawk you're using an alias anyway, so you can wrap the 4th method in a function instead: `sudodiff () { SUDO_EDITOR="/path/to/foo.sh" DIFF_FILE="$2" sudoedit "$1"; }`. Then the only clunky part is creating the wrapper script for first use.